# Add lines to sheet depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to add empty rows equal to the value in Column B
    Sub AddRows()

```
Dim cell As Range, numberRange As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Set numberRange = Range("B2:B5")

For Each cell In numberRange
    Set i = 1
    Set j = Int(cell.Value)
    For i = 1 To j
        cell.EntireRow.Insert xlDown
    Next i
Next cell

End Sub
```

For example, if a value of 2 was in B2, I would want two blank rows added in Rows 3:4.

Comment: I think you should start from Bottom to Top, unless you add the number of rows inserted to your counter for efficiency. You don't need to use `Set` for integers (Long it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, PatricK is right. You should start your insertions from the bottom of the range so that the new rows don't get caught up in the count of your existing rows.

```
Sub AddRows()

    Dim R As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For R = 5 To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(R, 2)
            i = int(Val(.Value))
            If i Then
                .Offset(1).Resize(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        End With
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Taking this one step further, would I be able to either 1) merge the new cells in Column B or 2) duplicate the value of the cell in Column B?

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. However, I don't do follow-ups. If you have another question please ask it in a new thread where some own input would be required. On principle: (1) Merging cells is rarely a good idea. It goes against the grain of Excel and will reduce the utility of the worksheet. (2) The value of the cell in column B is the number of rows inserted. If that is the value you want duplicated, use the range already defined while creating the new rows and assign the value `i` to it (or any other value, in fact).